# Outlook line-height ignored html mail

Tags: html, email, outlook, css

I created a short and simple HTML email for a newsletter. Everything displays perfectly on gmail and hotmail. However on Outlook there's some space between the images. 
Checking with firebug I can see that my line-height was ignored and the whitespace I'm seeing is actually the line height of my td. Here's a part of my code :

```
    <tr>
      <td width="10" height="80"  style="line-height:0px; line-height:0; border-right:1px solid #9cc020;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="15" height="80" style="line-height:0;" >&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="560" height="80"  colspan="5" style="line-height:0;">
         <img src="http://infos.mycookit.com/img/PL01bis/c1.jpg" alt="avec le code CHAMP" width="560" height="80" style="display:block">
      </td>
      <td width="10" height="80"  style="line-height:0; border-left:1px solid #9cc020;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

I have also tried setting font-size to 0, different ways for setting the line-height (%, em, px). I also removed the unnecessary white space between my tds and my imgs but line-height is just ignored completly. If I change it in firebug it works though. So I know the issue is none other than that.

Is there a way around this?

---edit-----
Oh and I also tried pretty much everything on this thread : [Line-height not working in Outlook 2010 for HTML Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980956/line-height-not-working-in-outlook-2010-for-html-email?rq=1)
including the weird  hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not use a "real" html renderer, so you're caught in a bad place. It may be that "line-height" does not work at all, or does not work for certain elements.

You can try a variety of alternate techniques. For example, wrap the content within the cell with an additional element, such as a div, span, etc., and give that element padding or margins. Example

```
<td>
   <div style="padding: 10px 0;">[mycontent]</div>
</td>
```

Comment: But wait I'm not getting this. My paddings/margins are okay, how could wrapping the affected <td>s in a span, div etc. would modify my line-height? I tried it out anyhow but it doesn't work, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: My point is "line-height" likely is not going to work :( See my updated answer

Comment: oh okay I get it now, sorry I was a little slow :/ So basically unless I change the global structure of my <table> I won't be able to display my <td>s without that damn line-height?

Comment: Sure, give it a try. There is no guide on what outlook does / does not support. At least not yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hope they'll come up with a better html renderer than words for the next version.